# How to achieve 2D jump similar to Alto Adventure?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have implemented through changing transform and also by applying velocity but didn't get that smoothness.

```
 // In Update 

 if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        isJumping = true;
        StartCoroutine(Jump()); 
        isJumping = false;
    }

IEnumerator Jump() 
{
    if (IsGrounded())
    {
        isJumping = true;
        player.gravityScale = gravityDuringJump;
        player.velocity = new Vector2(jumpSpeedInX, jumpSpeedInY);        
    }

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => IsGrounded() == false);
    isJumping = false;
}
```

Comment: That is kinda hard to tell with this little info. i'll lend you a hand though ; i implemented a simple clone of Alto's adventure in Processing (which might be Java, but you should be able to make out what i did). you can see it run & look at the source code here : https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/187806

Comment: i think the main key to making it work is keeping track of velocity the newtonian way. (use ineratia, integrate all changes in velocity, update position using velocity)

Comment: Few queries -> 1) Why are you setting `isJumping=false` right after starting the coroutine? I think this can have unintended consequences.  2) Have you tried implementing it without a coroutine.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyGroote